# POST requests with Python

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

I am trying to post a simple POST request with Python, but I get an unexpected error message.

A sample of the documentation is below :

- GET /configurations : get the list of configurations

  - Parameters: token (string)
- POST /configurations : post a new configuration

  - Parameters: token (string), configName (string), configParameters (array)

If I try the code below, the GET request works just fine:

```
parameters = 'token=' + token
url = base_url + '/configurations'
response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
print(response.json())
```

However, if I try the code below for the POST request, I get an error 401 : 'Invalid token'

```
configName = 'test_create_config' + str(random.randint(0, 1000000))
configParameters = [
    {'parameter': 1, 'parameterValue': '1'},
    {'parameter': 2, 'parameterValue': '0'}
    ]
body = {
        'token': token,
        'configName': configName,
        'configParameters': configParameters
    }

url = base_url + '/configurations'
response = requests.post(url, data=body)
print(response.json())
```

I am sure I am missing something, but I can't find what, as the token is identical to the one used for the get request.

EDIT :
Please find below the swagger documentation corresponding to the post request:

```
post:
        - configurations
      summary: Create a new configuration
      description: Create a new configuration and insert it in the database.
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: token
          description: Your token value.
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: query
          name: configName
          description: Your new configuration name.
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: query
          name: parameters
          description: Your new configuration parameter values. The payload is an array of strings '{"parameter":0,"parameterValue":"0"}' set for each parameter. In order to create it, you have to get the parameterVersion informations first.
          required: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Configuration has been created successfully.
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              status:
                type: string
                default: "DONE"
        '400':
          description: At least one of the request parameter is invalid and prevent the new configration creation.
        '500':
          description: Internal server error.
```

Comment: Please post the complete documentation for the POST API. Parameters can mean URL parameters & not body.

Comment: Are you sure the token does not go into the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Swagger doc you posted, the parameters you are passing should be going as URL query parameters - not the body.

```
- in: query
  name: token
  description: Your token value.
  required: true
  type: string
```

So you should change the request to:

```
response = requests.post(url, params=body)  # params are query parameters
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had assumed that query meant a different place than the URL